# sudo mkdir creates directory as nobody nogroup on mounted directory, then chown not permitted

Tags: command-line, mount, permissions, sudo, rsync

Could someone please help with the following?

If I create and "ll" a directory on a mounted disc, I get the following

```
xyz@c1:/home/Data6:sudo mkdir test
xyz@c1:/home/Data6:ll
drwxr-xr-x  2 nobody   nogroup  4096 Sep 15  2015 test/
```

Then the following command returns an error

```
xyz@c1:/home/Data6:sudo chown username test
chown: changing ownership of ‘test’: Operation not permitted
```

"sudo chmod" etc works, but not the "chown" (which I need for "rsync -a").

Why does sudo lose control over the ownership?

***relevant background info:***

Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS, 
disc mounted during boot as follows

```
xyz@c2:less /etc/fstab
/dev/sdc1 /Data6 ext4 defaults,acl 0 2

xyz@c2:less /etc/exports    
/Data6 *c1*/255.255.255.0(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,acl)

xyz@c1:less /etc/fstab
*c2*:/Data6 /home/Data6 nfs rw,hard,intr 0 0
```

The same happens if a file is copied via "sudo cp".

"lsattr" only shows the "e" attribute, no "i".

If login directly on **c2** (physical location of Data6) sudo can do everything (i.e. also "chown" of the directory created via "sudo" when on **c1**). It seems to be about running "sudo" as
a logged-in user who has "sudo" privileges on **c1** but then loses some of them if working on the disc mounted from **c2**. User has same name, id and group when running "sudo" on **c1** or **c2**

Is it maybe related to the "acl" option?

Any help very much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It seems that the files on c1 are being created as nobody; what's the result of running `sudo whoami` on c1?

Comment: @AnthonyGeoghegan

On both **c1** and **c2**, "sudo whoami" returns *root*.
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a security feature of nfs. You need to export it with flag `no_root_squash` so that a remote root will stay root on the filesystem.